# Zip file is corrupted when downloaded from server C#

Tags: c#, server, zip

I have a zipped a file and while downloading it from the server using C# code it is showing invalid while extracting, I have tried extracting the file directly from server and it was working.

So, here the file seems to be corrupted only during download. This was working correctly a few days before but now it is showing issue.

Can you please check my code and tell what could be the problem here, the same code works correctly in my local development environment.

Already tried,

1.Tried extracting the file directly in server and it worked , so issue must be with my downloading code.

2.The same download code is working correctly.

Note : File is already zipped in the server and the following code just downloads the zipped file, zipping is fine as file is opening in server

```
protected void linkbtntempdownload_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
            {
                string downloadlocation = string.Empty;
                if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] == "prod")
                {
                    downloadlocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Templates"].ToString();
                }else
                {
                    downloadlocation = Server.MapPath("~/TemplateFolder/Templates.zip");
                }

                Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "_Templates.Zip");

                Response.WriteFile(downloadlocation);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.SuppressContent = true;
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();



            }
```

Comment: What size is the file after downloading? Have you looked at the zip file contents with a text viewer like notepad to make sure you're not downloading a login page response or something?

Comment: Try adding headers as in the example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186153/9350365

Comment: Hi Jhileman , the downloaded file size is the same , I have verified that.

Comment: Hi, T.Czubaszek, the above code is already having headers, but the issue is still there, one thought is that could this be an issue related to server as the problem is only with zipped files or is it related to code.

Comment: If the file sizes are the same then you must be unzipping  file with a different utility so it unzips with one utility and not another utility.  When you are comparing size of files make sure that sizes are exactly the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi was able to rectify the issue finally. The reason was that the zip file was corrupted.

when zip file is opened with notepad it should start with P. But when opened our file we found an additional string was appended to the file. we were able to find that a **Respose.write("string")** was present in our server code that was appending as the additional string in the zip file. After removing it the file opened properly.